# Need to push jenkins log files to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to move jenkins logs to s3 bucket.
Can some one suggest how to move the log files.
Need to move console logs from aws instance.
Should I need to write script or the plugin is enough to push log files.
For every last 5 jobs it should move the files to s3.
Based on date, time, build number.

Answer (score 0):

You can create S3 bucket and mount it to EC2 instance. Detailed information about how to do that you can find [HERE](https://cloudkul.com/blog/mounting-s3-bucket-linux-ec2-instance/).
Once you mounted S3 bucket to your instance you need to say Jenkins that you want to store logs in that mount

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you Script instead of mounting If mounting is not working due to any reason you jobs will start failing  Using python script you can directly upload the logs to s3. It will be easier & reliable

Comment: can you please share the script @anmol Nagpal

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a script. But let me try if I can get something for you

Comment: Check this one might help https://github.com/vangheem/sync-ftp-to-s3/blob/master/sync-ftp-to-s3.py

Answer (score 0):

You first need to determine if your Jenkins server has access to S3 Bucket (*as it's unclear in your question*)

I am assuming that Jenkins server can access your S3 Bucket (the setup would generally involve the following steps):

- Your Jenkins instance is running on EC2 server and can access S3 either by

  - Using a pre-configured role attached to EC2 instance
  - Accessing S3 Programmatically
- S3 bucket is correctly configured (Permissions, Policies)

Once the setup is in place, you can use aws-cli to upload files into S3

[S3 CLI Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/)

Feel free to use Bash/Python/or any other language to wrote the script.